# Check if posts array has post which matches variable

Tags: php

I'm using [Kirby CMS](http://getkirby.com/).

I'm trying to get my latest post, but only if my latest post matches my $latest variable.

```
$today = new DateTime("now"); //Declare today
$startdate = new DateTime("2013-06-30"); //Declare startdate
$interval = $startdate->diff($today); //Find the difference between startdate & today
$latest = $interval->format('%a'); //Declare $latest variable to be that interval, formatted as integer

$posts = $pages->find('posts')->children(); //Declare posts

$latestpost = $posts->find($latest); //Find post which matches the $latest variable
```

I'm trying to get to the `$latestpost->url();` but only if `$latestpost` actually exists. When it doesn't at the moment, it comes up as a non-object.

Because of the way I'm getting `$latestpost`, `isset` and `defined` don't work.

How else could I do this?

Comment: Well what does `$posts->find(..);` return if it doesn't find anything?

Comment: It doesn't return anything.

Comment: So it's null? Use `is_null`.

Comment: @Rudi Visser That doesn't seem to work. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `$posts->find(..);` returns (looking at kirby's source it will be `null` or `false`), you can use a number of different checks.

Your best bet is to just use [`empty`](http://www.php.net/empty) as it's going to catch most of the cases, it will just be slightly less efficient than a specific check.

```
if (!empty($lastestpost)) {
    $url = $latestpost->url();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything still. 

I just tried 
       `if (!empty($latestpost)) {
  echo 'something';
 }
 else {
  echo 'nothing';
 }`

but that seems to always return 'nothing' no matter what I set $latest to.

Comment: So use `var_dump($latestpost);` and find out what it actually is. If it's always coming back as `null` or `false` then there's a different issue than checking it.